# There's no IPVLAN option in systemd.network man page

Tags: systemd, manpage

I read systemd.network man page, there is no IPVLAN option in [Network] section.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html

However I used that option in .network file, It works!

Is it accidentally omitted?

---

my simple three configure files.

```
#ipvlan0.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=ipvlan0
Kind=ipvlan

[IPVLAN]
Mode=L2

#ipvlan0.network
[Match]
Name=ipvlan0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

#wlp13s0.network
[Match]
Name=wlp13s0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
IPVLAN=ipvlan0
```

wlp13s0 is WiFi interface.

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: @IgnacioAra Added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you saw an older manpage version. Now the link you posted mentions the IPVLAN option. Obsolete question.